# Lwjgl 3 white screen

Tags: java, opengl, window, lwjgl, glfw

I try to render a Rectangle with VAOs, VBOs and DrawArrays(). Now I have set up my window with GLFW and a window appears. The window is always white even when I change the clear color and call glClear().

My window creation code:

```
public static long createWindow(int width, int height, String title){

    long window;
    window = GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title, MemoryUtil.NULL, MemoryUtil.NULL);

    if (window == MemoryUtil.NULL) {
        GLFW.glfwTerminate();
        System.out.println("Couldn't create window");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    GLFW.glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    GLFW.glfwSwapInterval(1);
    GLFW.glfwShowWindow(window);
    GLContext.createFromCurrent();
    GL11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    GLFW.glfwSwapInterval(1);
    GLFW.glfwShowWindow(window);
    System.out.println("OpenGL version: " + GL11.glGetString(GL11.GL_VERSION));
    return window;
```

My Mainloop:

```
public class Mainloop {
public static void mainloop(int vaoID,int vboID, int vertexCount, long window, ShaderProgram Shader){
    //Setup Before Rendering
    GL11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    GLFW.glfwPollEvents();
    //Bind Arrays
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    //Bind Shader
    Shader.start();
    //Render
    GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);
    //Clean-up Shader
    Shader.stop();
    //Clean-up Array
    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

GLFW windows use two color buffers. One of the buffers is the currently displayed one (i.e. the one that holds the content of your window as you see it now). The other one is in the background buffer. All OpenGL draw commands (`glClear`, `glDrawArrays`) render into the background buffer. This is done to avoid [screen tearing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing), which happens when you draw into the buffer while it is displayed, leading to parts of the image getting drawn and therefore displayed earlier than others, which results in a flickering effect.

Now because all the commands draw only in the background buffer, they are not actually displayed in the window, meaning a white background is all you see. You have to tell GLFW that you want to swap the buffers by calling `glfwSwapBuffers(window)`. Then the displayed buffer becomes the background buffer (and ready for new draw commands) and the background buffer becomes the displayed buffer, meaning that all you have drawn in the previous frame is now shown in the window. Then you can clear the background buffer and render the next frame.

**In Short:** Add `GLFW.glfwSwapBuffers(window);` at the end of `mainloop`.